# MYSQL - How to update sort according to counting the number of order

Tags: mysql

I have two tables that look like this.

**air_line_info**

```
code    sort 
BR      1
CI      2
CX      3
```

**orders**

```
order_id    air_line_code 
170101       BR
170102       CX
170103       CX
170104       BR
170105       CX
170106       CI
```

I'm trying to only use sql command to update air_line_info.sort by counting number of orders.

Down here is what I expect

**air_line_info**

```
code    sort 
BR      2
CI      3
CX      1
```

And here is my sql command

```
SET @sort = 0;
UPDATE 
  `air_line_info` 
SET `sort` = (@sort = @sort+1) 
WHERE 
  `air_line_code` = (SELECT `air_line_code` FROM `orders` GROUP BY `air_line_code` ORDER BY COUNT(`order_id`))
```

But I only got some message telling me that I have an error in my SQL syntax. Does anyone know what's the problem? If you have another way to solve it, I also want to know it, thanks.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: In this case, I got "Subquery returns more than 1 row".

Comment: What is mysql version?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with a subquery and the use of `ROW_NUMBER()` to ensure you don't get duplicate `sort` values:

```
UPDATE `air_line_info` nfo INNER JOIN (SELECT `air_line_code`, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(`order_id`) DESC, `air_line_code`) as `new_sort`
                                         FROM `orders`
                                        GROUP BY `air_line_code`) tmp ON nfo.`code` = tmp.`air_line_code`
   SET nfo.`sort` = tmp.`new_sort`
;
```

The subquery will give each `air_line_code` a unique number based on their order of appearance (from most-common to least-common) and alphabetic position.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on MySQL v8 or MariaDB that supports window function like `ROW_NUMBER()`, there's no better way to it. However, if you're restricted to older MySQL versions then I can understand why you're using this method. However, the way you're doing it now is invalid which is clearly told from the error message:

> Error 1242: Subquery returns more than 1 row

To illustrate what you're doing is something like this:

| Partial query | rows |
| --- | --- |
| .. WHERE `air_line_code` = | BR |
|  | CI |
|  | CX |

While the acceptable operation of using `=` is just with one row. Supposedly like this

| Partial query | row |
| --- | --- |
| .. WHERE `air_line_code` = | BR or CI or CX |

this will check and return result of either one of the three..

or maybe

| Partial query | row |
| --- | --- |
| .. WHERE `air_line_code` = | BR,CI,CX |

this will check all three combined as one value and won't return anything since you don't have `code` with `BR,CI,CX` as value.

Therefore, you need to change your query to a `JOIN`, slightly similar concept as [matigo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68886780/10910692) without the convenient of `ROW_NUMBER()` window function:

```
SET @sort := 0;

UPDATE 
  `air_line_info` A JOIN
  (SELECT air_line_code, @sort := @sort+1 AS sort
     FROM
        (SELECT air_line_code, COUNT(*) cnt
           FROM `orders` GROUP BY `air_line_code`) A
    ORDER BY cnt DESC) B 
ON A.code=B.air_line_code
SET A.sort = B.sort;
```

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=49406a5345e382308f0a128770a0e995)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
UPDATE air_line_info ali
    JOIN
    (
      SELECT COUNT(order_id) count_Order,air_line_code
      FROM order odr
      GROUP BY air_line_code
    )odr ON ali.Code=odr.air_line_code
    SET ali.Sort=odr.count_Order;
```